# Docker container sharing clipboard with host

Tags: vim, docker, containers, clipboard, host

I searched a bit on google but got no useful results.

I'm finishing dockerizing `vim` and a common problem showed up: its container just won't share the clipboard with the host.

I am used to building vim with `+clipboard`, and to being able to yank text and have it available to the host, or copying text in host and pasting in vim...

I thought about making `-v` volumes that would share this data but I still got nowhere.

I'm on Ubuntu 16.10.

Comment: For the downvoter, read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134306/where-do-i-post-questions-about-dev-ops

Answer (score 6):

The clipboard is almost certainly part of X, so you'll need to give the container access with:

```
docker run -e DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix your_image
```

Comment: That didn't work :( Try this: `docker run --rm -e DISPLAY -it -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix sree/vim '+set clipboard=unnamed'`, then yank text and paste on the host.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve this with the host being macOS?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Don't forget made X server allow your connect `xhost local:root`

Comment: This worked for me using neovim  (host machine Ubuntu 16.04 and docker container also based on an Ubuntu image). neovim doesn't need clipboard configuration like vim does. So if it doesn't work for you then it could also be that vim isn't correctly configured for clipboard

Comment: Update: also works with [vim8 compiled with +clipboard option](https://askubuntu.com/a/1027647/370026)

Comment: @NamPNQ's answer helped me. I always have this in `xhost +local:` ... it works for development use-cases; might not secure though!